# Why ListView.Adapter returns null when assigning a query

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin

I select the data from the meeting table and assign it an adapter. In doing so, I get a System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
private void LoadData()
        {
            listSource = DBConnection.selectTable();
            var adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, listSource);
            lstViewData.Adapter = adapter;
        }

static public List<Meeting> selectTable()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(Folder, "Organizer.db")))
                {
                    return connection.Table<Meeting>().ToList();
                }
            }
            catch (SQLiteException ex)
            {
                Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                EditText passwordEditText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.passwordEditText);
                lstViewData = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView);
            }
```

Meeting table structure:

```
[Activity(Label = "AddEvent")]
    public class Meeting
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int idLogin { get; set; }
        public int idContact { get; set; } 
        public string Place { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string Time { get; set; }
    }
```

I do this by analogy with this project: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-sqlite-database/

Comment: is `lstViewData` null?  Where are you declaring and instantiating it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, why you add the Activity attribute above the `Meeting`, If Meeting is not a activity, please remove it.

Then I wrote a demo about it. Here is running screenshot.

[image]

If you get `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Please notice your Listview if it is null, If so, You shoul move the `FindViewById` of `ListView` to above the `LoadData` method.

```
    lstViewData = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView);
    edtidLogin = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.edtidLogin);
    edtidContact = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.edtidContact);
    edtPlace = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.edtPlace);
    var btnAdd = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnAdd);


        db = new Database();
        db.createDatabase();
```

Here is my mainActivity code.

```
     public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    ListView lstViewData;
    List<Meeting> listSource = new List<Meeting>();
    Database db;
    EditText edtidLogin;
    EditText edtidContact;
    EditText edtPlace;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        lstViewData = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView);
         edtidLogin = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.edtidLogin);
         edtidContact = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.edtidContact);
         edtPlace = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.edtPlace);
        var btnAdd = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnAdd);


        db = new Database();
        db.createDatabase();
      //  InsertData(db);


        btnAdd.Click += BtnAdd_Click;
        LoadData();
    }

    private void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    var meeting=    new Meeting() { idLogin= Int32.Parse( edtidLogin.Text), idContact= Int32.Parse(edtidContact.Text) , Place= edtPlace.Text };
        db.insertIntoTable(meeting);
        LoadData();
    }

    private void InsertData(Database db)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();

        Meeting meeting = new Meeting() {
            idContact = 1,
            idLogin = 1,
            Place="Place1"
        };
         db.insertIntoTable(meeting);

        Meeting meeting2 = new Meeting()
        {
            idContact = 2,
            idLogin = 2,
            Place = "Place2"
        };
        db.insertIntoTable(meeting2);


        LoadData();
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        listSource = db.selectTable();
        var adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, listSource);
        lstViewData.Adapter = adapter;
    }
```

Here is my demo.
https://github.com/851265601/ListviewAndSqlite